# Dynamically generated javascript in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a database which holds some Javascripts.  The texts displayed to the user vary by section and languge.  The correct script needed is pulled using a SPROC.  This is then assigned in the controller to the ViewBag.  It is then displayed on the view.  Every thing works great except for one obstacle, it is adding jQuery function around my Javascript which then makes it not work.  I set a break point in the controller and can clearly see that it does not have the jQuery function when on the controller.  I thought perhaps if I added the script
tag in the controller and then wrote it to the view using Html.Raw that it might fix it but nope.

here is the code in the controller

```
 public ActionResult Personality(int AssessmentID, int ProfileID, int LanguageID)
    {
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
        var questions = db.CRI_AssessmentQuestions.Where(a => a.SectionID == 1 && a.LanguageID == LanguageID).OrderBy(a => a.Sequence);
        using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRI_Support"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand();
            object pages;
            oCmd.CommandText = "CRI_GetSectionCount";
            oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AssessmentID", AssessmentID));
            oCmd.Connection = oConn;
            oConn.Open();
            pages = oCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            oConn.Close();
            oCmd.Dispose();
            ViewBag.NumPages = pages.ToString();

            SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand();
            object mids;
            myCmd.CommandText = "CRI_GetAllowedMiddles";
            myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AssessmentID", AssessmentID));
            myCmd.Connection = oConn;
            oConn.Open();
            mids = myCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            oConn.Close();
            myCmd.Dispose();
            ViewBag.Middles = mids.ToString();

            SqlCommand tCmd = new SqlCommand();
            object totalQ;
            tCmd.CommandText = "PersonalityQuestionCount";
            tCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            tCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AssessmentID", AssessmentID));
            tCmd.Connection = oConn;
            oConn.Open();
            totalQ = tCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            oConn.Close();
            tCmd.Dispose();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            Object returnValue;
            cmd.CommandText = "CRI_GetNewScript";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SectionID", 1));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LanguageID", LanguageID));
            cmd.Connection = oConn;
            oConn.Open();
            returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            oConn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            script += returnValue.ToString() + "</script>";
            script = script.Replace("#iPageNumber#", "1").Replace("#iTotalPages#", pages.ToString()).Replace("#iAllowedMiddles#", mids.ToString()).Replace("#TotalQuestions#", totalQ.ToString());
        }
        ViewBag.Script = script;
        ViewBag.AssessmentID = AssessmentID;
        ViewBag.ProfileID = ProfileID;
        ViewBag.LanguageID = LanguageID;
        return View(questions);
    }
```

here is the code in the view

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Script)
```

and here is what is being returned

```
    <script type='text/javascript' >
(function($){

var message = "";
var pagenumber =  1;
var totalpages = 6;
var middles = 7;
var boolDisplayPassword = false;
var allow = "";
switch(middles){
    case 7:
        allow = "twenty (20) minutes";
        break;
    case 6:
        allow = "seventeen (17) minutes";
        break;
    case 5:
        allow = "fourteen (14) minutes";
        break;
    case 4:
        allow = "twelve (12) minutes";
        break;
    case 3:
        allow = "nine (9) minutes";
        break;
    case 2:
        allow = "six (6) minutes";
        break;
}
function instructions(){
    section="Personality"
    self.status=":  This is section "+pagenumber+" of "+totalpages
    message+="<br /><br /><p>The first assessment is a series of 76 questions that is not timed. There are no right or wrong answers. ";
    message+="Since we are interested in your style of doing things, it is in your best interest to answer the questions ";
    message+="with openness and honesty using your own value system, not what you think the Administrator wants you to say.";
    message+=" There is a consistency measure built into the assessment, so guessing at the intent of the questions is likely ";
    message+="to present a highly distorted profile of your results. Your candid responses are always the best answers.</p>";
    message+="<p>Answer each question by clicking the circle next to the answer you want to select.</p>";
    message+="<p><strong>DO NOT SELECT MORE THAN "+middles+" MIDDLE RESPONSES!</strong></p>";
    message+="<p>This exercise should take approximately " + allow +", but it is not timed. Answer each question honestly.";
    message+=" If you give untrue responses, they will show up in the assessment results!</p><br /><p>Please be aware that taking this assessment when ill, under the influence ";
    message+="of medications that can impact your mental alertness, or when you are feeling overly tired may negatively impact the results.";  
    message+="  We encourage you to take the assessment when you are rested and feeling well.</p>";
    message+='<br /><br /><p style="text-align:center;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="displayAssessment();" style="font:bold 1.2em arial" alt="click to continue"><strong>continue</strong></a></p>';   
    document.getElementById('message').style.display = "block";     
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = message; 
}
function returncheck(f){
    var totalMids = 0;
    var numCheckedResp = 0;
    var numQuestion = 0;
    var currOption = "";

    for(i=0; i < f.elements.length; i++){
        if(f.elements[i].type == "radio"){
            if(f.elements[i].name == currOption){   
                if(f.elements[i].checked){
                    numCheckedResp++;
                    if(f.elements[i].value == "2"){
                        totalMids ++;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(f.elements[i].checked){
                    numCheckedResp++;
                }           
                currOption = f.elements[i].name;
                numQuestion++;              
            }

        }
    }
    if(f.MidChoices.value == 0){
        f.MidChoices.value = totalMids;
    }
    if(!(numQuestion == numCheckedResp)){
        ErrMsg = "You have answered "+numCheckedResp+" of the "+numQuestion+" questions.<br />Please go back and answer all questions.";
        document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = ErrMsg;
        document.getElementById('DisplayUserError').style.visibility = 'visible';
        return false;
    }else{
        if(totalMids > 7){
            ErrMsg = "You have answered "+totalMids+" middle Questions.<br />Please go back and change "+(totalMids - 7)+" of the answers.";
            document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = ErrMsg;
            document.getElementById('DisplayUserError').style.visibility = 'visible';
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
function displayAssessment(){
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('message').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('AssessmentData').style.display = "block"; 
}

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

this is NOT jQuery  so it should not have

```
(function($){
})(jQuery);
```

What do I need to do to get this to display properly?

Comment: I think Eduardo got the issue right but as an aside you should not be stuffing the ViewBag with variables you want on your view. It was created so you could have access to those variables out of the scope of your view in _Layout.cshtml. Create a PersonalityViewModel.cs class with the properties you want your view to have access to then initialize it and populate its values in the controller and pass it to your view.

Comment: If this is the actual code, there's something else going on here. Your function builds the script using `"<script type=\"text/javascript\">"`, which would be `<script type="text/javascript">` after unescape, but your "what is being returned" shows `<script type='text/javascript' >`. Note the difference in quote marks and spacing. There's obviously something going on that's not shown here.

Comment: Yes I saw that too.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `Personality.cshtml` view. There you will find the  `(function($){` code

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause.  I have the MVC Controls Toolkit in  the project.

There was the following code

```
 public static class MySuperPackage {
    public static void PreStart() {
        MVCControlsToolkit.Core.Extensions.Register();
        //System.Web.Mvc.GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MVCControlsToolkit.ActionFilters.PlaceJavascriptAttribute());
    }
}
```

Commenting out the adding of the filter resolved the issue